# I can't Install Apk from android app bundle using command prompt

Tags: android, apk, android-app-bundle

I referred bundletool command after that I created APKs using the command prompt. But I can't install apk in the device.

My path of apk's file is- `D:\testRelease\XYZ.aab`

So I try this command to install:-

> --> bundletool.jar install-apks --apks=D:/testRelease/XYZ.apks

but can't get any output. I also tried to get connected to device-spec but still can't get any output

Comment: But you can build bundle also Navigate to Build->Build Bundle(s)/Build apk(s)->Build Bundle

Comment: I have done that but after that, I want to install apk from Build bundle(s) (.aab file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a precondition remember to create an environment variable "ANDROID_HOME" and set it to where the Android SDK is located on your Development machine.

So for Windows it may be

> ANDROID_HOME =  "C:/MyAndroid"

Assuming you are testing on just one device first generate the bundle only for your connected device using the following.

```
bundletool build-apks --connected-device  --bundle="\somepath\app-release.aab" --output="\somepath\release.apks" --ks="somepath\keystore" --ks-pass=pass:cleartextpasswd --ks-key-alias=keyalias --key-pass=pass:cleartextpasswd
```

Note the use of the option

> --connected-device

Now to install on a specific device use the following command:

> bundletool install-apks --apks="somefolder\release.apks"
>   --device-id="yourdeviceidstring"

Get the device id string from the ***Settings*** section of your device.